# Edit registry values

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I have to edit certain registry settings of my WinCE device. I can execute commands on the device only through the telnet service.

How can I do that?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. You would need a "telnet2registry" gateway?!?

Answer (score 2):

Execute `conmanclient2.exe`, followed by `cmaccept.exe` - this will open a corecon connection pipe-then use the Remote Registry Editor in the Studio 2008 tools.